# Eclipse unable to build apk after source changed

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I'm using Eclipse 3.7 from last 4 days its unable to build new apk when source modified. I **enabled build automatically.** If i clean the project apk file deletes from bin folder.

Comment: what do you mean by source changed ? is it modified or re-allocated ?

Comment: restarted it many times its not working, from last 4 days its happening lik this